# Angular google maps @agm/core

Tags: angular, google-maps, agm

I'm using `@agm/core` for my project and I want the data layer to style dynamically.

1. When I click on the single layer it has to change the color. This is done using data layer click functionality
2. When I select a radio button or a check box then the whole data layers has to get updated with a different color which is not happening.

Trying to complete the task with the changes but haven't found any help.

Comment: See [ask]. You aren't going to get much traction without a [mcve]. And you also need to tell us what your expected and real results were.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply share a style object between data layers:

```
// HTML
<agm-data-layer [geoJson]="geoJsonObject" [style]="styleObject"></agm-data-layer>
<agm-data-layer [geoJson]="geoJsonObject2" [style]="styleObject"></agm-data-layer>

// TS
public styleObject = {
  clickable: true,
  fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
  strokeWeight: 0
};

public changeStyle() {
  this.style = {...this.style, fillColor: "#000000"};
}
```